# connection reset by peer upstream issue

Tags: nginx, config, centos7, fastcgi, osticket

I've installed `OSticket` application on my `nginx` server.

The webpage is opened only first time, if I simply refresh the page, it gives `connection reset by peer upstream` error..

I tried to change `fastcgi_read_timeout` and `max_execution` time as described in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/502-bad-gateway-with-large-file-uploads and https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/configure-max_execution_time-in-php-fpm-using-nginx/#, that didn't help.

nginx error log:

```
2017/08/07 22:15:08 [error] 26877#26877: *42 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.231.1.79, server: web.com, request: "GET /ticket/logo.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "web.com", referrer: "https://web.com/ticket/"
```

PHP-FPM error log:

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 26883 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 4270.119171 seconds from start
```